# Producing a map from columns with highest number

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology

I'm trying to produce a map with different categories based on four columns (lag, mlag, mhog and hog), these are income status. I want each polygon in the map to be represented by whatever number who is the highest among these four columns, thus making it a map with four different categories that represent the most prevalent income in that area.

I.e. for FID 0 it will be 'hog'

I figure it must be something related to *Symbology* but there is no option to select categories based upon highest number or something like it.

I hope I was clear enough, the task is quite simple I think but I can't really see right now how I should do it.

[image]

Comment: Do you want a map of four categories or for example a map that show the actual highest number?

Comment: Oh, I should've mentioned it. I want a map with four categories separated by colour. But defined by the highest number of these four columns.

Comment: Please **edit** the question in  response to requests for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Script below will add a new field called highestcat and fill with name of the highest category. You can then use this field to set the symbology:

```
import arcpy,operator
fc=r'C:\TEST.gdb\polygons' #change to match your data
arcpy.AddField_management(in_table=fc, field_name='highestcat', field_type='TEXT',field_length=10)
fieldlist=['lag','mlag','mhog','hog','highestcat']
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,fieldlist) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        index, value = max(enumerate(row[:4]), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
        row[4]=fieldlist[index]
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

[image]

Comment: This solved my problem, thank you very much for writing this script for me!